# Auto format an existing Excel report

Tags: excel, vba

I use an app to analyse some data and and the create an Excel report. So my starting point is an existing excel with 5 columns and a variable number of rows. What I am looking for is to just auto-format the excel report. Ideally, just space the column widths and alternate the coloring of the rows. Is this possible with this script?

Thanks
Ash

Comment: You probably should just apply a [table](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Overview-of-Excel-tables-7ab0bb7d-3a9e-4b56-a3c9-6c94334e492c) to your report. Start recording a macro, apply the table via interface, stop recording, and examine and adapt the recorded macro.

Comment: If all you have on your worksheet is the report you described there is no need to treat it as a table. Just skip that part and follow the rest of @Yan F.'s advice.

Comment: I recorded this macro and it almost does what I wanted it to.:

`code` Sub FormatLeadReports()
    Columns("A:F").Select
    Columns("A:F").EntireColumn.AutoFit
    Range("A1").Select
    Selection.CurrentRegion.Select
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range("$A$1:$F$3"), , xlYes).Name = _
        "Table1"
    Range("Table1[#All]").Select
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").TableStyle = "TableStyleMedium2"
End Sub
`code`
Problem is that the number of rows usually is different between the sheets. Instead of Range("$A$1:$F$3"), how do I make it auto detect the last cell.

Comment: While it's easy to find the last row of your report, it's not needed when you applying a table: Excel will figure out automatically what the last row is. In your macro you just remove the line Range("Table1[#All]").Select

Comment: Pardon, the above was incorrect: in your macro replace the line ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range("$A$1:$F$3"), , xlYes).Name = _ "Table1" with ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Selection, , xlYes).Name = "Table1"

Comment: THANKS!! That's exactly the small change I was looking for. Works well with sheets that vary in number of rows. Appreciate your help!